# Cognos Percentage per Category of a total

Tags: cognos

I have a cross tab report which has the following

On the labels on the side are the types of commodities bought
On the top labels are the shop names
The data consists of number of units sold

Example:

```
         Shop1         Shop2          Shop3      Total
Toys      25            50             25         100
Cars
Trains
```

I am new to Cognos but what i want to do is get the percentage of per shop of how many items were sold per category.

So for example if i sold 100 toys in total and i have 3 shops. I want the whole value of number of toys for shop 1 to be 25 items sold which is 25% of the total items sold that month and 50 items for shop 2 again worth 50% of the total items sold for that month

Does anyone know how to do this in a cross tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Queries tab and add to your query new expression

```
[Items Sold]/Total([Items Sold] for [Category])
```

Then add you field to your Crosstab